# Unitary "phase" in *-algebra

Tags: ring-theory, c-star-algebras

I'm looking into unital *-algebras and I'm trying to understand if the following is true:

If $A, B$ are elements of the algebra such that $AA^* = BB^*$ then there exists a unitary element $U$ such that

$$A U^* = B U$$

I know that this is true for non-necessarily-commutative C*-algebra, but it seems to me that the proofs use spectral theory and singular value decomposition, which do not seem to arise without the C*-condition.

The *-algebra may not be even commutative (think about the algebra of polynomials with complex matrix coefficients equipped with transpose conjugation).

Do you have any proof/counterexample for this?

Comment: Either there's a typo  in the question or I'm very confused.  The equation $AA^*+BB^*=1$ should hold for $A=1$ and $B=0$.

Comment: @AndreasBlass You're right! thanks for pointing it out, it should be $AA^* = BB^*$. I'm fixing the typo.

Answer (score 1):

Without closure, there could be many things missing from those that make C$^*$-algebras useful.

Consider $\mathbb C[t]$ (complex polynomials of a real variable) as your algebra. Since unitaries are invertible, it is immediate that the only unitaries are the scalars, that is the constant polynomials of absolute value $1$. Let
$$
p=1+it,\qquad\qquad q=1-it.
$$
Then
$$
pp^*=|1+it|^2=1-t^2=|1-it|=qq^*.
$$
But $p$ and $q$ are not scalar multiples of each other, so there cannot be any unitaries $u,v$ with $pu=qv$.

Comment: Hi Martin. Perhaps change the variable from $x$ to $t$ in $\mathbb{C}[x]$.

Comment: Indeed, edited. Thanks!

Comment: @MartinArgerami Thank you for the example, so I know for sure that this cannot follow just from the axioms of *-algebra. My context is a bit more particular, namely, it is the algebra of Laurent polynomials with matrix coefficients $M(2, \mathbb{C})[z, z^{-1}]$, where the conjugation takes the adjoint of the matrices and inverts $z$. I know for sure that there are non-trivial unitaries, but I'm trying to understand which conditions I should have in order to have a unitary that satisfies that equality.

Comment: I think you have the same problem in your algebra. You can consider $p=(1+iz)\otimes I_2$ and $q=(1-iz^{-1})\otimes I_2$, adjoints of each other, so $pp^*=qq^*$. Because they are "scalar" matrices, so would your unitary need to be, which brings the problem to polynomials again. And there is no polynomial $v$ with $v(1+iz)=1-iz^{-1}$.